# Why I can't edit any question anymore?

Tags: support

Is there a reason I can't edit a question anymore?

It says

> This account is not allowed to suggest edits.

I mainly removed what is not caught by the bot, this means greetings, thanks and pleas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many posts can use a lot more editing than simply removing salutations.

The community that reviewed your suggestions most likely rejected most of them as too minor:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

With enough of these rejection, the system blocks you from additional suggestions, as they are deemed bad suggestions.

Frankly, with 40 suggestions in as many minutes, I am not surprised you ended up blocked.

---

In short - you just went through an edit blitz, instead of doing the responsible thing and taking your time to properly edit all the faults in the posts that you did suggest edits for.

Many of these edits were seen as too minor (given that they were made on posts that could use more substantial edits) and rejected as result.

Comment: Just wanted to help the community in what the bot and other users didnt seem to have caught. thank you for the answer.

Comment: I fully appreciate wanting to help. That's good. However, just doing a "cleanup" of this sort isn't helpful. It causes others to have more work in the review queues - if you want to fix a post, fix all of it.

Comment: Lesson learned. Next time will edit responsibly.

Comment: Excellent! See you around ;)